# Radbutton not firing Webmethod through JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, telerik

I have this button:

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="GetBookingButton" runat="server" Skin="Silk" Text="Get booking" CssClass="get-booking-button" OnClientClicked="onGetBookingClick"></telerik:RadButton>
```

With this client-side method:

```
function onGetBookingClick(sender, eventargs) {            
            var text = $(".write, .write-hex").val();            

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "GetBooking.aspx/BookingSearch",
                data: JSON.stringify({ text: text }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () { },
                failure: function () { }
            });

            return false;
        }
```

And this server-side method in the code behind:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string BookingSearch(string text)
    {
```

I have tried various things: Removing static from the Webmethod, making Webmethod void, removing return value from the client side method, etc. But the Webmethod does not fire.

Except for once. I just recently switched the above JSON post to a small JSON post method we've designed in house, without good results, and then back to the above code. And then, when using the above code - it worked! Once.

I have verified that the var "text" looks allright and that Jquery is loaded.

Comment: 1. You should probably pass parameters to `onGetBookingClick`.  2. `$(".write, .write-hex").val()` would take value of only first selector.

Comment: I'm not sure of how to pass parameters to the event actually. But I'll look into it. As for the second part, I know. And this is intended. I know at this point that there will be exactly one object with the .write class OR one object with the .write-hex class. But the code is probably not very clear.

Comment: Try setting the RadButton's AutoPostBack property to false, the postback from the button is likely breaking the request to the service you make via the jQuery call.

Comment: What if you use `data: { text: text }`?